# Using REGEX in if-elsif-else-end

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to use REGEX to do a `if-then-elsif-then-else-then-end`
Example:

```
s = "foobar123"
if end of s is 3
  then return "foo"
elsif end of s is 2 
  then return "bar"
else
  then return "foobar"
end
```

I found `(?(?=condition)(then1|then2|then3)|(else1|else2|else3))` from http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html but don't know how to make it work in this case.
Here is my Regex for `if-then-else-then-end`:

```
/(?=.*[3])(foo)|(bar)/
```

- if string end with 3
- then return foo
- else return bar

I think can write another if-else in else of parent phase but can't :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were on the right track with using alternation, but you don't need lookaheads.

```
/.*(foo).*3$|.*(bar).*2$|.*(foobar).*/
```

And you would have to return:

```
$1$2$3
```

I have all the `.*`s because I assume you're using `foobar` as a placeholder.

Comment: Hm, would someone explain the downvote? To be clear, I'm aware that regular expressions can't magically generate "return values," but if the text to "return" is within the match, then in many implementations one is able to concatenate all of the captures.